# Converting post to Wiki answer

Tags: discussion, bug

We had a very [interesting question about an old translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570935/takes-advantage-of-their-head-rope-runs-the-risk). I posted an answer which was partly inaccurate, but then I received a lot of good suggestions and I was able to combine those into a fairly authoritative answer.

This was a collaborative effort, yet when I tried to convert to a Wiki answer (twice!) by checking the box and saving,  it did not take. Did I do it wrong?

Is there some kind of restriction on Wiki conversion i.e. time, number of edit, etc that prevented this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, but I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Dan'ku...much appreciated. How do I close this puppy?

Comment: I'm not sure what the real restrictions are. Leaving the [meta-tag:bug] should attract devs.